# Best practices for volumes that need to be accessed from multiple pods on EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes

Currently [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) says that by default EKS on AWS supports through AWSElasticBlockStore plugin only ReadWriteOnce access mode on EBS.

I need my EKS cluster configured with multiple pods having read-write access to single volume, or at least one read-write and others read-only.

I was able to configure my cluster with [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) provisioner but would like to know if there are some alternatives, especially that use EBS volumes. Could not find any better solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

EFS is the right solution. You can create an external file system and then your pods can access it in ReadWriteMany mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already have EFS running and wanted to know if there is anything better. EFS is less performant comparing to EBS, especially if you want to use it to serve web apps with many small files. Also, EFS volumes management in Kubernetes is additional overhead.